# For all e-mail entries that do not have a firstname, replace with 'Gamer'

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I manage a large email list for my gaming society.  In column A, I have the e-mails, and in column B, I have the usernames.  I populate column B with a formula that extracts the name of the user from their e-mail address, which is often in the firstname.lastname@email.com form.  Column B therefore returns "Firstname" after I run the formula if the user's email is in the firstname.lastname@email.com format.

Sometimes, however, the emails have just the initial of the first name (f.lastname@email.com) and, in these case, I want to have Column B return the word 'Gamer' rather than, for example, the first letter of the user's email.

Here is the script I use at the moment, which current deletes all rows with four or more numbers:

```
    function removeNumbers() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {

var row = values[i];

if (row[0].toLowerCase().indexOf("robot") > -1) {
  sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
  rowsDeleted++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your shared spreadsheet, use this

```
function firstName() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var lr=sheet.getLastRow()
  var val = sheet.getRange(2,1,lr-1,2).getValues();//get the col A email addrs
  var newVal=[]//new array for before fitst period
  for (var i = 0; i <= val.length-1; i++) {
    var str=val[i][0].split(".")//split email at period
    var len=str[0].length // determine lenght of number string of first split
  if(val[i][1]=="inactive"){
    newVal.push(["inactive"])
    continue
  }
  if(len<=1){//if 1 or less
    def="Gamer"
    newVal.push([def]) //put Gamer in new array
  }
  else{
   newVal.push([toTitleCase(str[0])]) //keep first name
}}
  sheet.getRange(2, 2, newVal.length, 1).setValues(newVal)//set new values in col B
 }
function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) {
        return txt.charAt(0)
            .toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1)
            .toLowerCase();
    });
}
```

This well also run on the active sheet.

Comment: Thanks again, Ed.  Is there a way to put this (or any other formula) into a script?

Comment: I attempted to insert that line into the following script, to no avail:

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

    var cell = sheet.getRange("B");
cell.setFormula("=arrayformula(if(len(regexextract(B:B,"[^.]*"))<=1,"Gamer",regexextract(B:B,"[^.]*")))");

Comment: Terribly sorry, I'm not sure how to format that correct so that it displays correctly.

Comment: The formula was ment to be entered difectly into B2. I added a script version of the answer. If you need more help share a sample spreadsheet and I can show you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ed.  Really appreciate your help.  Here is the link to my test sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RQxZ2yMeARdjGAcoJfx3Mtgdb7IM35WUICk7I-Q5AuU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Is there a way to make the script sheet-agnostic, so that I do not have to change the name of the sheet in the script every time I want to apply it to a new sheet?

Comment: Wonderful!  Thank you very much.

Comment: One further question for the script.  If the cell in Column B includes "@", how do I replace the entire value of the cell with "Gamer"?

Comment: I have tried the following with no luck in the shared google sheet:

    if(val[i][1].indexOf("@") > -1){
    newVal.push(["gamer"])
    continue 
  }

Comment: I put your '@' script right after the 'inactive' check and it worked fine. What error do you get?

Comment: Thank you, Ed.  It's working finely now.  I had placed my line in the wrong location.

Comment: A further question about this line:  var str=val[i][0].split(".") //split email at period

If I want the email split at either "." or "-" or "_", what would the correct syntax be?  I tried || and |, but neither work.  Is this related to the split function?